# Нужна ли запятая после слова «варить» и слова «еде»? Почему нужна?

Tags: пунктуация

И приходилось маме их вновь и вновь варить(,)
И «трубами» мальчишку и день и ночь кормить.

Не помогли рассказы о правильной еде(,)
И лодочки из мяса в подливке, как в воде.

Answer (score 1):

Указанные запятые не нужны.

(1) Союз *и* соединяет однородные члены предложения *варить* и *кормить*.
(2) Союз *и* соединяет однородные члены предложения *рассказы* и *лодочки*. (Предполагается, что автор хотел сказать, что не помогли рассказы и лодочки, но возможен и другой смысл, тогда знаки препинания нужно расставить по-иному).

Comment: Спасибо большое!!